# How to match a webcam captured image with another image in Java Swing?

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, javacv

I am trying to make a hand sign converter in java for my university project . For that i have to match hand sign image and find out the meaning of that particular hand sign .

i have already tired this way to find out the difference percentage between two image .But this way doesn't get me the perfect result .

```
        imgA = ImageIO.read(fileA); 
        imgB = ImageIO.read(fileB); 
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    { 
        System.out.println(e); 
    } 
    int width1 = imgA.getWidth(); 
    int width2 = imgB.getWidth(); 
    int height1 = imgA.getHeight(); 
    int height2 = imgB.getHeight(); 

    if ((width1 != width2) || (height1 != height2)) 
        System.out.println("Error: Images dimensions"+ 
                                         " mismatch"); 
    else
    { 
        long difference = 0; 
        for (int y = 0; y < height1; y++) 
        { 
            for (int x = 0; x < width1; x++) 
            { 
                int rgbA = imgA.getRGB(x, y); 
                int rgbB = imgB.getRGB(x, y); 
                int redA = (rgbA >> 16) & 0xff; 
                int greenA = (rgbA >> 8) & 0xff; 
                int blueA = (rgbA) & 0xff; 
                int redB = (rgbB >> 16) & 0xff; 
                int greenB = (rgbB >> 8) & 0xff; 
                int blueB = (rgbB) & 0xff; 
                difference += Math.abs(redA - redB); 
                difference += Math.abs(greenA - greenB); 
                difference += Math.abs(blueA - blueB); 
            } 
          } 

        // Total number of red pixels = width * height 
        // Total number of blue pixels = width * height 
        // Total number of green pixels = width * height 
        // So total number of pixels = width * height * 3 
        double total_pixels = width1 * height1 * 3; 

        // Normalizing the value of different pixels 
        // for accuracy(average pixels per color 
        // component) 
        double avg_different_pixels = difference / 
                                      total_pixels; 

        // There are 255 values of pixels in total 
        double percentage = (avg_different_pixels / 
                                        255) * 100;
```

I expect the output to be that much accurate ,it can distinguish different hand sign and find me the correct match

Comment: You could try using deep learning with tensorflow

Comment: Dear Scary Wombat , Thank you for your suggestion . it would be more helpful if you may be more specific about this

Comment: Have a look at https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/basic_classification

Answer (score 0):

for image manipulation using java you should use javacv which is wrapper over opencv . Though javacv is not an official release from opencv still you can find many useful functionalities in javacv.

The official site for javacv is 
[http://bytedeco.org/](http://errorsexceptions.blogspot.com/2016/01/basic-image-manipulation-in-javacv.html)

To get started with javacv you can follow articles from the below site

[Basic image manipulation using javacv](http://errorsexceptions.blogspot.com/2016/01/basic-image-manipulation-in-javacv.html)

[Capturing image from webcam using javacv](http://errorsexceptions.blogspot.com/2016/01/capturing-image-using-webcam-in-javacv.html)

[Hand and finger detection using javacv](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/12/hand-and-finger-detection-using-javacv.html)